# Best practice for integrating Kafka and HBase

Tags: apache-spark, hbase, apache-kafka, apache-storm, flume

what are best practices for "importing" streamed data from Kafka into HBase?

The usecase is as follows: Vehicle sensor data are streamed to Kafka. Afterwards, these sensordata must be transformed (i.e., deserialized from protobuf in humanreadable data) and stored within HBase.

1) Which toolset do you recommend (e.g., Kafka --> Flume --> HBase, Kafka --> Storm --> HBase, Kafka --> Spark Streaming --> HBase, Kafka --> HBase)

2) What is the best place for doing the protobuf deseralization (e.g., within Flume using interceptors)?

Thank you for your support.

Best, Thomas

Comment: Another option is Kafka - Camus - HDFS -> MR to convert into HBase HFile -> bulk load into HBase. Particularly if input data is ingested in large batches.

Comment: You could also use Apache Flink Streaming.

Comment: The sensor data are streamed "separately" to kafka, i.e., there is no bulk load of sensor data into Kafka. Instead, a single message holds relevant sensor data of one vehicle at a specific point of time.

Answer (score 4):

I think you just need to do **Kafka -> Storm -> HBase**.

Storm: **Storm spout** will subscribe to Kafka topic. 
Then **Storm bolts** can transform the data and write it into HBase. 
You can use HBase client api in java to write data to HBase from Storm.

I suggested Storm because it actually processes one tuple at a time. `In Spark streaming, a micro-batch is processed`. However, if you would like to use common infrastructure for Batch and Stream processing then Spark might be a good choice.

If you end up using Spark then also your flow will be **Kafka -> Spark -> HBase**.

Comment: Why do you prefer Storm over the other alternatives (Flume, Spark Streaming)?

Comment: @ThomasBeer :Spark Streaming is not real streaming. Its micro-batch processing. Although, you can call that Stream Processing. This is a good read: http://www.sqlstream.com/blog/2015/03/5-reasons-why-spark-streamings-batch-processing-of-data-streams-is-not-stream-processing/
Flume is primarily used for log aggregation. I am not confident about its popularity to be used a Stream Processing Engine.

Answer (score 0):

1) I recommend to use 'Kafka Connect' Connector to stream your data from Kafka to HBase. There are a couple sink connectors from the Kafka community:
http://docs.datamountaineer.com/en/latest/hbase.html
https://github.com/mravi/kafka-connect-hbase
2) As for transforming your data, you can use Kafka Streams which is a lightweight Java library included in Kafka since Kafka 0.10 release in May 2016: http://kafka.apache.org/documentation/streams